# Pdfbox - Issues with image quality in PDF's

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I understand that pdfbox allows you to insert jpegs into generated PDF's, however the resulting image quality is fairly poor. My initial work has proven this assumption. Does anyone out there who has used pdfbox have any suggestions? I'm trying to generate dynamic text/tabular content for print on a weekly basis. Perhaps there's a way to tweak the resulting pdf quality somehow? Or even some other opensource suggestions?

I've looked into using iText, but it's licensing is really driving me away from using it. Here's a sample of how I currently add an image to a document.

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("img.jpg"));
    PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(document, in);
    ....
    contentStream.drawImage(img, 10, 700);
```

Comment: In which way the quality is poor? I would have to look it up in source but I doubt PDFBox does anything social to the JPEG, most likely it merely embeds it as is. Thus, quality issues most likely are related with the original JPEG or the PDF viewer or printing Module you use.

Comment: No matter how I resized the image in the PDF, be it exact point-for-point, or smaller, the jpeg constantly lost quality. It remained pixelated and messy, often much larger than it should have been. I ended up using BFO's PDF library instead, which also supports PNG and I have yet to have any image problems.

Comment: I agree with the comment of mkl. Anyway, the next release of PDFBox (1.8.5) will support PNGs properly (new PDPixelMap() already works in some cases now, but not all).